# Parallelize the validation of 1 epoch with training of another in pytorch lightning

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I am training a pytorch lightning model on a GPU. I validating it at every epoch and each validation run takes about 30 mins on a dataset big enough to give me a reliable estimate.

I would like to speed up the process by validating in parallel (on a CPU) with the training of the next epoch. Does pytorch lightning support this functionality?

The only solution I could think of is to run a parallel thread that would be waiting for a new epoch to finish (with the weights then stored in a checkpoint file).